# Why does modal content not hide when modal is not shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, modal-dialog

I am using Zurb's [jQuery Reveal Modal](http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) plugin to create a pop-up box with a Vimeo video. However, the last video displays over the content as soon as the page loads and doesn't disappear, and the other videos do not disappear after hitting the close button on their respective modal window. The box and the other content within it will disappear, but the iframe for the video does not.

Here is the markup for the trigger and modal box:

```
<div class="videoEntry">
    <h3>Community Involvement</h3>
        <a href="#" data-reveal-id="modal4"><img class="videoThumb" src="images/community-video_thumb.jpg" /></a>
        <p>Corvalent Corporation CEO Ed Trevis talks about Chirofit's Corporate Wellness programs and Dr. Mo's involvement in the Cedar Park and Austin communities.</p>
        <div id="modal4" class="reveal-modal">
            <h1>Modal Title</h1>
            <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/74992379" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/74992379">Chirofit and Community</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/user20693845">Chirofit</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS and JS files have not been changed at all, and are included as they come. The reveal.css file is in the header and the jquery.reveal.js file is in the footer just below the call to the most recent version of jquery hosted on Google's CDN.

I'm at a loss about what could be causing this. I'm doing this for a friend and I'm starting to wonder whether his table-based site might be the problem. It often causes unexpected behavior. Any input with this would be tremendously appreciated.

The site can be viewed [here](http://staging.chirofitwellnesscenter.com/videos.html), in case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error in jquery.reveal.js on line 118 (comma is missing) :

```
modal.css({'display' : 'none' 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
```

maybe this cause the problem?

Comment: That would be what was causing the popup not to work. I added "display: none" to see if that would prevent the iframe from showing when the popup is not displayed. The popup now works again, but the iframes are still acting funny.

Comment: I also get an error in the Google Analytics javascript at the bottom of videos.html. Did you try to comment that code to see if the modals works?

Comment: I just gave it a go, unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the cause either.

Comment: After fixing the error you found, I was able to get the problem with the other videos continuing to display after closing their boxes to go away, by adding the comma after 'none', but the last video still displays from the start. If you have any ideas I would be very thankful to hear them!

Comment: Nevermind, I used Vimeo's old embed code since the iframe was the only thing that was showing outside the modal. I think his table-based site didn't agree with the iframe. Thanks for your help!